# Communication between my computer and my mobile using bluetooth

Tags: java, vb.net, java-me, bluetooth

I am trying to create a client server application. Server side is vb.net program which runs in my computer and listens for commands. Client side is J2ME application which is in my mobile that will send commands.

I have a Bluetooth dongle for my computer and I am going to use Bluetooth as the medium. Wifi is not supported by my mobile.

I know basics of VB.Net(using VB2010). And I have Oracle's J2ME SDK installed in my computer and I have created small(simple applications) applications using it.

So, I have searched in Google. But most of the results are confusing. Today I found [Wireless Communication Library .NET Edition](http://www.btframework.com/). But documentation is very poor. So I don't know in between things, that is connection establishment. But I can code how to execute when each command is received at both sides.

I need a start. Anything that will help me for achieving or using Bluetooth connection, in this project is appreciated.

Comment: ok. someone down voted! One thing, if u can't post the reason. Please don't down vote it. I am not against down voting. But please post the reason for down voting like "I have down voted ur question because..."., as a comment in here.

Comment: Wasn't me, but I would guess its because you haven't tried anything yourself before coming here.

Comment: thanku for replying. I have already said that searching in google didn't showed any good results. But the one that i found (WCL.Net) has poor documentation(literally nothing). But i have seen another question asked in here which uses a java library. But if i use that, i should use JAVA for server application also. Instead, i like to use vb.net. I really don't like the idea of downvoting without posting any comments. Why they downvote and hide after that ? Q:http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121392/negative-marks-for-questions

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-down-voted-how-should-i-react-to-this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your just wanting simple data transfer between the pc and phone, then the serial port protocol over bluetooth will probably meet your needs.  Google for vb.net serial port, that should find you something that will get you started.

Comment: I have a doubt. My phone is Nokia made and i have PC Suite installed in my computer. So, when i connect turn on my mobile, it will automatically detect my mobile. And when checked there is COM7 and COM8 available(COM7-COM10 are bluetooth serial ports). So, if i use one of them for my use, will it cause problems ? That is, is Nokia PC suite also using that ports ? Will it conflict ? thanku